# How can I set the Tor IP to a GeoLocation?

Tags: geolocation, ip, tor

I'm building a bot therefore I want to use Tor. More, I want to set my Ip to chosen Geoloaction or Country. Is this possible?

Heres my Tor initializing code

```
public static void setUp() throws Exception {
    //driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();    
    //driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    String torPath = "/Applications/TorBrowser.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox";
    String profilePath = "/Applications/TorBrowser.app/TorBrowser/Data/Browser/profile.default/";
    FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile(new File(profilePath));
    FirefoxBinary binary = new FirefoxBinary(new File(torPath));
    driver = new FirefoxDriver(binary, profile);        
    baseUrl = "https://qa2all.wordpress.com";
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you have to do is edit the `torrc` config file used by the Browser Bundle (usually located at `Browser/TorBrowser/Data/Tor`) and add a config value like so:

```
ExitNodes {US}
```

Where `US`  is the country code of the IP you want to use.   You can specify multiples by comma separating them.  Note: Country codes must be enclosed by `{}` in order to work.  See the [`ExcludeNodes`](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html.en#ExcludeNodes) documentation for details on what's accepted.